# How to create a custom widget in kivy-python

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I am trying to make a custom button with border and rounded corners using kivy and I'm new to kivy and python (and its object oriented concepts).
I have partially implemented what I want but whenever I try to increase/decrease the border size or corner radius using an event like **on_press** it happens but as soon as I resize the window, the border_size/corner_radius becomes to what it was initialized.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App


class CustomButton(Button):
    border_color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    corner_radius = NumericProperty(0)
    bg_color = ListProperty([0, 0, 0, 1])
    border_width = NumericProperty(0)


Builder.load_string("""
<CustomButton@Button>:
    
    # should I define border_color, corner_radius, bg_color and border_width
    # here or within my python script like I did here?
    
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: ''

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.border_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [self.corner_radius]

        Color:
            rgba: self.bg_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: [i - 2 * self.border_width for i in self.size]
            pos: [i + self.border_width for i in self.pos]
            radius: [self.corner_radius - self.border_width if self.corner_radius != 0 else 0]

""")


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass


Builder.load_string("""
<RootWidget>:
    CustomButton:
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        text: 'HELLO'
        border_width: 0.1 * self.height
        on_press:
            self.border_width = 0.2 * self.height
""")


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


TestApp().run()
```

Result:-

[After running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7DDm.png)

[After pressing the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAQOL.png)

[After resizing the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvOAP.png)

I have tried this code snippet in a separate .kv file as well but I'm getting the same result.
Also I have tried to implement border using **Line rounded_rectangle** but its kinda bleeding.

Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The line in your `kv`:

```
    border_width: 0.1 * self.height
```

will reset the `border_width` whenever the `height` of the `CustomButton` changes. So when you resize the window, the above code is activated.

You can avoid this problem by making the `0.1` or `0.2` values into `Properties` like this:

```
    bw_ratio: 0.1
    border_width: self.bw_ratio * self.height
    on_press:
        self.bw_ratio = 0.2
```

Another option is to define an `on_size()` method for `CustomButton`:

```
def on_size(self, instance, new_size):
    self.border_width = 0.2 * new_size[1]
```

And remove the `border_width` stuff from the 'kv'.
Then you can do anything that you want for setting `border_width` in the new method. Just don't do anything in that method that changes the `size` of the `CustomButton` or you will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Well that worked for me but what if I want the border width to be some percent of self.width I would need to have other variable or what if I want the border width to depend on some expression, this solution unfortunately would not work. Please tell me a solution which would work in these situations (things like depending on an expression). Thank you

Comment: Added another possible solution to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I guess the instant I assign border_width equal to 0.1 * self.height some method by kivy is created and is fired the next time whenever the height changes is this theory right?

Comment: Yes, whenever you reference a `Property` in the `kv`, it automatically sets up a binding to that `Property` and triggers the referenced rule. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#relation-between-values-and-properties).

Comment: Then what is the problem in this situation? When I initialize the border_width for the first time every thing works fine i.e. the border_width changes as the height changes but when the value of border_width changes the second time via an event like on_press, it changes but when the height changes, it becomes what it was initialized for the first time.

Comment: That is because the original rule is still there and active. The `on_press:` just gets run when the `Button` is pressed, but does not change the original rule. So, whenever the `height` changes, the original rule is triggered again.

Comment: So, isn't there any way to get the behavior I want?

Comment: Yes, you can. But, if you want to use a general expression, then you can't use a simple `border_width:` rule. The `on_size()` method allows you to use any logic you desire.